# Putting space between 2 buttons in a td

Tags: html, css

i have a td

```html
<td align="left">              
    <button class="button_tabel"><div class="button_tabel_text_hero"> hero</div>   </button>  
    
    
                       <!-- todo Put a gap   here 48 px  -->           
    
    
    <button class="button_tabel"><div class="button_tabel_text_zero"> zero </div>   </button>          
    
</td>
```

How can i put a gap of around 48 px in between these two buttons which lie in this td

i wish to put space separately out of buttons so that this can be changed from  backbone easily without impacting other components

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put some margin on one of the buttons:

```html
<td align="left">              
  <button class="button_tabel">
    <div class="button_tabel_text_hero"> hero</div>
  </button>  
  <button class="button_tabel">
    <div class="button_tabel_text_zero"> zero </div>
  </button>          
</td>
```

```css
.button_tabel:first-of-type {
  margin-bottom: 48px;
}
```

Comment: wont thius increase button size and make those look awkward

Comment: @MAG no, the `margin` property does not increase the size of the elements, but applies some space outside of them. You can learn more about it here: https://www.w3schools.com/Css/css_margin.asp

Answer (score 1):

Add `margin-left:48px` on `.button_tabel`

```
.button_tabel + .button_tabel{
   margin-left:48px;
}
```

Comment: wont this increase button size and make those look awkward –

Comment: @MAG update my answer check now

Answer (score 1):

Just select the first class and add a margin:

```css
.button_tabel:first-child{
  margin-right:48px;
}
```

```html
<td align="left">              
    <button class="button_tabel"><div class="button_tabel_text_hero"> hero</div>   </button>  
    
    
                       <!-- todo Put a gap   here 48 px  -->           
    
    
    <button class="button_tabel"><div class="button_tabel_text_zero"> zero </div>   </button>          
    
</td>
```